# R Loop for dplyr summarize function

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have a dataset ('DF1') that I want to know how many times each instance of 'Species' appears per 'Date' per 'Site'. My actual data set has five dates per site and there are ten sites, but I've condensed it quite a bit here.

| Site | Date | Minute | Segment | Species | Vtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 5 | 1 | AMCR | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 5 | 1 | LISP | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 5 | 2 | AMCR | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 5 | 2 | LISP | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 5 | 2 | LEGO | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 11 | 1 | LISP | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 11 | 1 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 11 | 1 | RCKI | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 11 | 2 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 11 | 2 | LISP | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 11 | 2 | AMCR | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 12 | 1 | LISP | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 12 | 1 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 12 | 1 | AMCR | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 12 | 2 | LISP | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 12 | 2 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 12 | 2 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 13 | 1 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 13 | 1 | AMCR | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 13 | 1 | LISP | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 13 | 1 | RCKI | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 13 | 2 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 13 | 2 | LISP | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 13 | 2 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 15 | 1 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 15 | 1 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 15 | 2 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 15 | 2 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 17 | 1 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 17 | 1 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 17 | 2 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 17 | 2 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 17 | 2 | AMCR | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 18 | 1 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 18 | 1 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 18 | 2 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 18 | 2 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 20 | 1 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 20 | 1 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 20 | 2 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 20 | 2 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 20 | 2 | AMCR | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 21 | 1 | AMCR | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 21 | 1 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 21 | 1 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 21 | 2 | YRWA | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 21 | 2 | AMCR | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 21 | 2 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 25 | 1 | AMCR | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 25 | 1 | SAVS | Song |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 25 | 2 | AMCR | Call |
| SVC | 5/27/2021 | 25 | 2 | SAVS | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 2 | 1 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 2 | 1 | PISI | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 2 | 1 | STJA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 2 | 2 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 2 | 2 | STJA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 2 | 2 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 3 | 1 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 3 | 1 | RECR | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 3 | 1 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 3 | 1 | YRWA | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 3 | 2 | MOCH | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 3 | 2 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 3 | 2 | RECR | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 3 | 2 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 3 | 2 | YRWA | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 3 | 2 | AMRO | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 13 | 1 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 13 | 1 | YRWA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 13 | 1 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 13 | 1 | LISP | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 13 | 2 | YRWA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 13 | 2 | RECR | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 13 | 2 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 13 | 2 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 13 | 2 | LISP | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 14 | 1 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 14 | 1 | YRWA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 14 | 1 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 14 | 1 | LISP | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 14 | 2 | YRWA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 14 | 2 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 14 | 2 | LISP | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 17 | 1 | LISP | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 17 | 1 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 17 | 1 | YRWA | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 17 | 1 | AMRO | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 17 | 1 | PISI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 17 | 2 | LISP | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 17 | 2 | YRWA | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 17 | 2 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 18 | 1 | YRWA | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 18 | 1 | LISP | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 18 | 1 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 18 | 2 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 18 | 2 | LISP | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 18 | 2 | YRWA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 18 | 2 | RECR | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 21 | 1 | YRWA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 21 | 1 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 21 | 1 | LISP | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 21 | 1 | PISI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 21 | 2 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 21 | 2 | YRWA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 21 | 2 | LISP | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 22 | 1 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 22 | 1 | YRWA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 22 | 1 | LISP | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 22 | 2 | YRWA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 22 | 2 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 22 | 2 | LISP | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 22 | 2 | AMRO | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 22 | 2 | HAFL | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 23 | 1 | YRWA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 23 | 1 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 23 | 1 | HAFL | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 23 | 1 | LISP | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 23 | 2 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 23 | 2 | RECR | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 23 | 2 | LISP | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 23 | 2 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 23 | 2 | AMRO | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 23 | 2 | YRWA | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 25 | 1 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 25 | 1 | RCKI | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 25 | 1 | HAFL | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 25 | 1 | LISP | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 25 | 1 | YRWA | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 25 | 2 | DEJU | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 25 | 2 | LISP | Call |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 25 | 2 | HAFL | Song |
| TMC | 6/1/2021 | 25 | 2 | RCKI | Song |

I can summarize the counts for one Species at a time using this code:

```
DF1 %>% group_by(Site,Date) %>% 
  filter(Species=="AMCR") %>%
  summarise(count_Species = n())
```

This will return the count for 'AMCR' for each site on each date, but it would be too tedious to do this for each Species and then combine all those results into one dataframe.

Is there a way to loop this for each unique instance of species and then paste them together into one dataframe?

Thank you!

Comment: Remove the `filter` and add `Species` to your `group_by()`?

Comment: That gives me the total count for each Species over the entire dataframe, not the counts per day per site.

Comment: When I say "add Species to your `group_by()` I mean `group_by(Site,Date,Species)`" which will give you a count for each site/date/species combination, not for the whole data frame.

Comment: That worked just great! I can't believe it was that simple. I just needed to add one more term. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `count` from `dplyr` package!

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  count(Species, Date, Site)
```

```
   Species Date      Site      n
   <chr>   <chr>     <chr> <int>
 1 AMCR    5/27/2021 SVC      11
 2 AMRO    6/1/2021  TMC       4
 3 DEJU    6/1/2021  TMC      15
 4 HAFL    6/1/2021  TMC       4
 5 LEGO    5/27/2021 SVC       1
 6 LISP    5/27/2021 SVC       8
 7 LISP    6/1/2021  TMC      16
 8 MOCH    6/1/2021  TMC       1
 9 PISI    6/1/2021  TMC       3
10 RCKI    5/27/2021 SVC       2
11 RCKI    6/1/2021  TMC      14
12 RECR    6/1/2021  TMC       5
13 SAVS    5/27/2021 SVC      18
14 STJA    6/1/2021  TMC       2
15 YRWA    5/27/2021 SVC      12
16 YRWA    6/1/2021  TMC      17
```

Comment: This also works seemingly just as well as the other solution in the comments of my question.

Comment: `count` is really powerful. See its argument with `?count` (sort, weight, name)!

Comment: I will say that answer automatically sorts the dataframe alphabetically which is an added bonus.